# Is it possible to have in SBT a Test Fixture source folder?

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, unmanaged

Reading the following SBT documentation:

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Appending-Values.html

And also

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Classpaths.html

I can get on how to create a test source folder with only utils classes to be consume both by the tests in the same project and in all other projects that depend on it.

I tried the following but got compilation issues:

```
Test / sourceDirectories := Seq( baseDirectory.value / "testFixtures", baseDirectory.value / "test")
```

And also the following but this time sbt does not find any tests in the project:

```
sourceDirectory in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test"


Test / unmanagedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "testFixtures"
```

any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just putting those classes in a package `utils` inside your tests sources?

Comment: Because we are in transaction to gradle and we want to support the test fixture source set feature. So we need those in a separate source folder

Comment: I really don't understand why you need them in a different folder, but in case. Why not just create a different module for those files? - Also, I would recommend you to use standard paths and features so you don't hate your build definition.

Comment: Look here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures

Comment: We don’t want another module we just want to separate the tests from the tests utils in the same module. And make sure the tests depends on the tests utils.

Comment: _"we just want to separate the tests from the tests utils in the same module"_ that is just a package or a module. Depending on how you want to publish them or not.

Comment: Thank @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez for the help